# SQLiteDatabase - How to use where clause?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

```
public Cursor fetchTimetable() {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_TIMETABLE, new String[] {TIMETABLE_ROWID,    TIMETABLE_MODULECODE, TIMETABLE_MODULENAME, TIMETABLE_ROOM, TIMETABLE_LECTURER, TIMETABLE_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

For example if i wanted TIMETABLE_MODULECODE = 123. How would i do this, i have read its the first null. I have tried this below but still doesnt work

```
public Cursor fetchTimetable() {
    String a = "TIMETABLE_CODE = ADD";
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_TIMETABLE, new String[] {TIMETABLE_ROWID, TIMETABLE_MODULECODE, TIMETABLE_MODULENAME, TIMETABLE_ROOM, TIMETABLE_LECTURER, TIMETABLE_TIME}, a, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
db.query
        (
                TABLE_NAME,
                new String[] { TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO },
                TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID,
                null, null, null, null, null
        );
```

**TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID,** here "=" is the where clause

Comment: This works however i get an error message when using letters. But if i use numbers it works

Comment: if you want to use a string you can fire the query as                  Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, CUSTOMER_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {GENERIC_ID_KEY,ADDRESS_KEY, PHONE_KEY, MAIL_KEY,CUSTOMER_NAME_KEY}, GENERIC_ID_KEY + "=?", new String []{ customerDbId}, null, null, null, null);

Answer (score 11):

My working example with where args (it's more clear with using it):

```
        String [] settingsProjection = {
                DBContract.Settings._ID,
                DBContract.Settings.COLUMN_NAME_USER_ID,
                DBContract.Settings.COLUMN_NAME_AUTO_LOGIN
        };

        String whereClause = DBContract.Settings.COLUMN_NAME_USER_ID+"=?";
        String [] whereArgs = {userId.toString()};

        Cursor c = db.query(
                DBContract.Settings.TABLE_NAME,
                settingsProjection,
                whereClause,
                whereArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
```

Answer (score 7):

What exactly does "still doesn't work" mean?

The following code should work just fine:

```
public Cursor fetchTimetable() { 
    String[] columnNames = new String[] {TIMETABLE_ROWID, TIMETABLE_MODULECODE, TIMETABLE_MODULENAME, TIMETABLE_ROOM, TIMETABLE_LECTURER, TIMETABLE_TIME};
    String whereClause = "TIMETABLE_MODULECODE=123"; 

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_TIMETABLE, columnNames, whereClause, null, null, null, null); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

the right syntax is

```
String[] projection= {column names};
String[] where={"values for where clause"}; //this must be array     
public Cursor fetchTimetable() { 

    return mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, projrction, "columname"+"=?", where, null, null, null); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lalit, your codes work for me.
I don't know why you don't get upvote. please attach some links too

Answer (score 2):

The simple way:

```
return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column1 = "+ someValue, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Use this query:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

//Cursor cursorr = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

Cursor cursorr =  db.rawQuery("select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE_EHS + " where " + TASK_ID + "='" + taskid + "'" , null);

    if (cursorr.moveToFirst()) 
   {

        do {

            // your code like get columns

            }
         while (cursorr.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking against a string value you'll want to wrap the string in quotes like below:

```
dbHelper.COL_EMAIL +"='"+givenEmail+"'",
```