# Wanted to add where clause with query method to get row with particular id

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

```
    Cursor cursor=resolver.query(TimeTableUtil.TIME_TABLE_URI,projection,null,null,null;
```

Wanted to add where clause in the method

Comment: And it still does not work if you add the missing `)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLiteDatabase - How to use where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444593/sqlitedatabase-how-to-use-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use Room library. easier and more performance

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room